# Regular Expression for password in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to apply the regular expression to Password field that contain **at least one UpperCase , one LowerCase, one number and one Special symbols**

**(Eg : Ss@1)**

Comment: Lots of examples of [password regex here](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this. I think the better solution is to enforce a minimum length, though. Even without uppercase or numbers, adding two random letters to a password makes it over six hundred times more secure. You might also try techniques like letting users know when they have an especially common password (that might still pass your regex) if security is a real concern

see:
https://xato.net/passwords/more-top-worst-passwords/

Answer (score 1):

one special character, one uppercase, one lowercase(in any order)

```
^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$
```

You can use http://rubular.com/ to validate regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
^[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$
```